# X :compact and continuous function $f(x)\neq x$

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) be a compact metric space and $f:X\to X$ be a continuous function such that $f(x)\neq x,\: \forall x\in X$.

Prove that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $d(x, f(x))>\epsilon$, for all $x\in X$.

I don't know how to approach. Is there someone to help?

Comment: $d$ is a mteric on $X$. $f(x)\in Y$. Thus, $d(f(x),x)$ is not defined

Comment: try to prove the contraposite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous for any metric space.

This implies that the function $F(x) = d(x, f(x))$ is continuous from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as well, and this function never assumes $0$ and is positive. Its image is compact (as $X \times X$ is), so has a minimum $\varepsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot understand it. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: @topy, what exactly do you have problems with?

Comment: I don't know why 1st sentence implies the next.

Comment: Actuaully, the 1st sentence is also hard. Also I don't know why its image is compact.

Answer (score 0):

If not, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ of points of $X$ such that $\lim_n d(x_n,f(x_n))=0$. Pick a converging subsequence $x_{n_j} \to x_\infty$, and deduce that $f(x_\infty)=x_\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $g:X\rightarrow X$ that sends $x$ to $d(f(x),x)$. Verify that $g$ is continuous. By the extreme value theorem, $g$ attains a minimum on $X$. Tihs minimum can't be zero  because $f(x)\not=x$ for every $x$. The minimum of $g$ is the $\epsilon$ which you are looking for.